# Try to convert code o fa small flashcard app from Tkinter into Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Here is the code translated in kivy (I tried my best) the code run but the app does not launch, I tried to debug as well but nothing.

The goal of this little app it is to show flash cards of a certain language and then 3 second after turn the card to show the answer and if the user click on "is_known" button, then the word of the card is deleted from the list to keep only unknown words of the user

Its maybe a dependency problem, or a the run() function which is maybe not correctly set up, I have no more ideas now.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.clock import Clock
import pandas
import random

class FlashcardApp(App):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create the app layout
        self.layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

        # Create the card title label
        self.card_title = Label(text="French", font_size=40)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.card_title)

        # Create the card word label
        self.card_word = Label(text="", font_size=60)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.card_word)

        # Create the card background image
        self.card_background = Image(source="images/card_front.png")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.card_background)

        # Create the "I know this word" button
        self.known_button = Button(text="I know this word", on_release=self.is_known)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.known_button)

        # Create the "I don't know this word" button
        self.unknown_button = Button(text="I don't know this word", on_release=self.next_card)
        self.layout.add_widget(self.unknown_button)

        # Load the words to learn data
        try:
            self.data = pandas.read_csv("data/words_to_learn.csv")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            self.data = pandas.read_csv("data/french_words.csv")
            self.to_learn = self.data.to_dict(orient="records")
        else:
            self.to_learn = self.data.to_dict(orient="records")

        # Show the next card
        self.next_card()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if len(self.to_learn) == 0:
                break

            self.next_card()

            # Wait for the user to click on a button
            Clock.schedule_once(self.wait_for_user_input, 1)

    def wait_for_user_input(self):
        # Check if the user has clicked on a button
        if self.known_button.state == "down":
            self.is_known()

        elif self.unknown_button.state == "down":
            self.next_card()

    def next_card(self):
        # Choose a random card to learn
        self.current_card = random.choice(self.to_learn)

        # Update the card title and word labels
        self.card_title.text = "French"
        self.card_word.text = self.current_card["French"]

        # Update the card background image
        self.card_background.source = "images/card_front.png"

        # Schedule a timer to flip the card after 3 seconds
        Clock.schedule_once(self.flip_card, 3)

    def flip_card(self):
        # Update the card title and word labels
        self.card_title.text = "English"
        self.card_word.text = self.current_card["English"]

        # Update the card background image
        self.card_background.source = "images/card_back.png"

    def is_known(self):
        # Remove the current card from the list of words to learn
        self.to_learn.remove(self.current_card)

        # Save the updated list of words to learn to a CSV file
        self.data = pandas.DataFrame(self.to_learn)
        self.data.to_csv("data/words_to_learn.csv", index=False)

        # Show the next card
        self.next_card()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    FlashcardApp().run()
```

Comment: You need a `build()` method for your `App` class. It should return the root widget that contains your GUI.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).